# Pandas - split column with dtype object (string) to dtype list by specifying delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

Given data in a csv like below

```
A,B,C-1,D,BTP,Type C1,Type C2
0,1,0,0,0,,Type B
0,2,1,1,14,Type B,Type B
0,3,2,2,28,Type A,Type B
0,4,3,3,42,"Type A,Type B","Type A,Type B"
0,5,4,4,56,Type A,"Type A,Type B"
```

I'm reading this into a dataframe `df`. Need to split `Type C1' column by` ,`and store as a list in place such that I can do some lookup with`%in% of operator. Here is what is being done.

```
df["Type C1"] = df["Type C1"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)
```

Was expecting to get a `list` for column `Type C1` - however it was still a string with the part from `,` stripped out as below.

```
      A  B    C-1          D    BTP                        Type C1                Type C2
0     0  1    0            0     0                            NaN                         Type B
1     0  2    1            1    14                         Type B                         Type B
2     0  3    2            2    28                         Type A                         Type B
3     0  4    3            3    42                         Type A                  Type A,Type B
4     0  5    4            4    56                         Type A                  Type A,Type B
```

For row #3 was expecting `[Type A,Type B]` for column `Type C1`

The reference I'm using to do this is from [Pandas Split strings into two List/Columns using str.split()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-split-strings-into-two-list-columns-using-str-split/) Example #1 output.

Comment: Don't use `expand=True`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct, `split()` returns a list by default:

```
df['Type C1'] = df['Type C1'].str.split(',')
df['Type C2'] = df['Type C2'].str.split(',')

   A  B  C-1  D  BTP           Type C1           Type C2
0  0  1    0  0    0               NaN          [Type B]
1  0  2    1  1   14          [Type B]          [Type B]
2  0  3    2  2   28          [Type A]          [Type B]
3  0  4    3  3   42  [Type A, Type B]  [Type A, Type B]
4  0  5    4  4   56          [Type A]  [Type A, Type B]
```